# compare two objects and return true if part of the object key value pair exists

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to compare two objects and return true or false based on the below logic.

```
const expectedValue = {
            city: "San Jose",
            state: "california",
            zip: "95234"
         }

const actualValue = {
            address: "5543322 Adam St",
            city: "San Jose",
            state: "california",
            zip: "95234",
            country: "USA"
}
```

When the above objects are compared, it should return "**TRUE**", as expectedValue's  key value pair exists in the actualValue.
I couldn't find anything in lodash documentation , is there any good solution for this?

Thank you in Advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on the array produced by [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to test if every key/value pair in the expected matches the actual:

```js
const expectedValue = {
   city: "San Jose",
   state: "california",
   zip: "95234"
}

const actualObject = {
   address: "5543322 Adam St",
   city: "San Jose",
   state: "california",
   zip: "95234",
   country: "USA"
}


let test = Object.entries(expectedValue)
          .every(([key, value]) => actualObject[key] === value )

console.log(test)
```

It will return true if every key/pair from `expectedValue` exists in the `actualObject` and matches the value, false otherwise.

There is an edge case where a property exists in `expectedValue` with a value of `undefined`. You can handle this by testing `actualObject.hasOwnProperty(key) && actualObject[key] === value` if you need to.

Comment: The things we learn on StackOverflow ... never used `every` before and I was creating a solution with a `forEach` loop through `Object.keys` to compare each entry ... but your solution is so much cleaner ... +10 if I could :)

Comment: @balexandre yeah JS definitely has some nice little functional tools these days. Both `every` and `some` are super-useful.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash has the [`_.isMatch()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isMatch) function:

> Performs a partial deep comparison between object and source to
>   determine if object contains equivalent property values.

```js
const expectedValue = {
  city: "San Jose",
  state: "california",
  zip: "95234"
}

const actualObject = {
  address: "5543322 Adam St",
  city: "San Jose",
  state: "california",
  zip: "95234",
  country: "USA"
}

const result = _.isMatch(actualObject, expectedValue)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```